# Time picker with working time to work

Tags: android, eclipse, datetimepicker, timepicker, android-timepicker

I've problem with time picker: i want create an app that automatically calculate the working time to work (if i start at 8am and end at 11:30 I must have 3:30 as a result).

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID2:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener2, hour1, minute1,false);

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID3:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener3, hour, minute,false);

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID4:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener4, hour, minute,false);         

}


    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;
        txtTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(padding_str(hour)).append(":").append(padding_str(minute)));
    }
};


private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener4 =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
    hour4 = selectedHour;
    minute4 = selectedMinute;
    txtTime4.setText(new StringBuilder().append(padding_str(hour4)).append(":").append(padding_str(minute4)));
    if (txtTime4 == null) {
        hour4 = 0; hour3=0; minute4=0; minute3=0;
    }

    txtTimeresult1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(padding_str((hour1-hour)+(hour4-hour3))).append(":").append(padding_str((minute1-minute)+(minute4-minute3))));

}};
```

Comment: Clearly state your question. What is the problem you are having? What have you tried yourself? You can't just expect people to investigate your code and improve it for you.

Comment: I've create this string txtTimeresult1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(padding_str((hour1-hour)+(hour4-hour3))).append(padding_str(minute))); and I want that automatically calculate the working time to work. For example if hour1=12, hour=8, hour4=18, hour3=14, it must calculate 8 hour (I've start to work at 8 to 12 in am and 14 to 18 in pm). The code function but if in pm I don't work and I don't insert hour3 and hour4 it make me an error!

Comment: Change it in the question